# Broadcast a HATEOAS object as a websocket message with a Content-Type other than application/json

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, jackson, spring-hateoas

I need to render the class below (among several other classes that `extends RepresentationModel`) both on a `RESTController` and as a broadcast message to a websocket.

```
@Getter
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)
@Setter
public class MessageWrapper extends RepresentationModel<MessageWrapper> {
    private Object message;
    private String simpleName;

    public MessageWrapper(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.simpleName = message.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

I render it to the response body using the code below:

```
@RequestMapping(
    headers = {
        "Content-Type=application/json",
        "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = "application/hal+json",
    value = "/thread/{threadId}/message")
public HttpEntity<MessageWrapper> post(...) {
    MessageWrapper wrapper = ...

    HttpEntity<MessageWrapper> entity =
        new ResponseEntity<HateoasWrapper>(wrapper, HttpStatus.OK);

    return entity;
}
```

And it produces the following truncated response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
...
Content-Type: application/hal+json

{
    "_links": {
        "previous": {
            "href": "/thread/1044/message/86"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "/thread/1044/message/87"
        }
    },
    "message": {
        ...
    },
    "simpleName":"..."
}
```

Notice the `Content-Type` of the response and the `_links` object attribute above. I created a javascript handler for that `Content-Type` and that `_links` attribute is critical. Now on a separate event sometime later, I need to broadcast the exact same JSON String to a websocket. So I did this:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void broadcastToUser(StompPrincipal principal, MessageWrapper wrapper) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor simpHeaderAccessor =
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);

    simpHeaderAccessor.setUser(principal);
    simpHeaderAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
        principal.getUsername(),
        "/broadcast",
        wrapper,
        simpHeaderAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
}
```

And it produces the following message:

```
a["MESSAGE
destination:/user/broadcast
content-type:application/json
subscription:sub-0
message-id:tluhntae-0
content-length:267

{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "previous",
            "href": "/thread/1044/message/86"
        },
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "/thread/1044/message/87"
        }
    ],
    "message": {...},
    "simpleName": "..."
}

"]
```

Notice that it has the `links` attribute instead of `_links`. Also notice that instead of having an object value like the one above, it has an array of objects as value. I am suppose to use the same javascript callback to the `RESTController` response above but cannot since the `links` attribute has a different structure. I can marshall it on the javascript side but I rather not an instead attempted to configure it to render it as what I expected it to be rendered. I read that this is because I am rendering the websocket message as `application/json` instead of `application/hal+json` thats why it uses `links` instead of `_links`. So I set the `Content-Type` of the message as HAL before broadcasting it:

```
MimeType applicationJson;
        
if(RepresentationModel.class.isAssignableFrom(body.getClass())) {
    applicationJson = new MimeType("application", "hal+json");
} else {
    applicationJson = new MimeType("application", "json");
}

simpHeaderAccessor.setContentType(applicationJson);
```

It throws the following error though:

```
2020-10-26 23:40:40.799 ERROR 6200 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Unable to convert payload with type='MessageWrapper', contentType='application/hal+json', converter=[CompositeMessageConverter[converters=[org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter@66389c40, org.springframework.messaging.converter.ByteArrayMessageConverter@724493b5, org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter@1228bacc]]]] with root cause

org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Unable to convert payload with type='MessageWrapper', contentType='application/hal+json', converter=[CompositeMessageConverter[converters=[org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter@66389c40, org.springframework.messaging.converter.ByteArrayMessageConverter@724493b5, org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter@1228bacc]]]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.doConvert(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:230) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:211) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at dev.gideon.chatapp.service.BroadcastService.broadcastToUser(BroadcastService.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    ...
```

I really need to set the websocket message's `Content-Type` to HAL for it to be marshalled the way I expected it to be. Is there anyway to implement this? I am asking this question because aside from me not wanting to do separate javascript codes that handles the json object with the `links` attribute with an array value and the `_links` attribute with the object value, I also believe that it is indeed proper for it to be broadcasted with a HAL `Content-Type` so that other clients aside from my own will treat it as such and not just a normal JSON broadcasted message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default `MessageConverter` for websocket broadcast message of `Content-Type` `application/hal+json`. I need to implement my own `MessageConverter` for my custom MIME type. I created a converter that `extends AbstractMessageConverter`:

```
public class HalMessageConverter extends AbstractMessageConverter {
    public HalMessageConverter() {
        MimeType hal = new MimeType("application", "hal+json");
        this.addSupportedMimeTypes(hal);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return RepresentationModel.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object convertToInternal(
        Object payload,
        MessageHeaders headers,
        Object conversionHint) {

        TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
            new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(RepresentationModel.class);

        Module module = new Jackson2HalModule();
        LinkRelationProvider provider = new DefaultLinkRelationProvider();

        Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator instantiator =
            new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(
                provider,
                CurieProvider.NONE,
                MessageResolver.DEFAULTS_ONLY);

        ObjectMapper mapper = converter.getObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.setHandlerInstantiator(instantiator);

        try {
            String payloadJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
            byte[] bytes = payloadJson.getBytes();
            return bytes;
        } catch(JsonProcessingException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to create a custom class since the method `addSupportedMimeTypes` is `protected`. The `convertToInternalMethod` holds the conversion logic. The `Jackson2HalModule` class is what I've been looking for all this time. This class is the reason why `links` becomes `_links` when a `Response` is sent with a `Content-Type` of `application/hal+json`.

After creating this custom `MessageConverter`, I added this to the default converters of the application:

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(new HalMessageConverter());
        return false;
    }
}
```